# Errors occur when Hibernate Mapping Files and pojo's from the database

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans-8

I'm new one to java and net beans. I used hibernate framework in one of the project. I tried to Hibernate Mapping Files and pojo's from the database. Given names for the class correctly without giving null values. But I get this error [image: Error]

This is my message.log file

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class name cannot be null
    at org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.CustomClassLoader.loadClass(CustomClassLoader.java:97)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.util.CustomJDBCConnectionProvider.getConnection(CustomJDBCConnectionProvider.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2442)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2434)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.buildSettings(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.buildSettings(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.readFromJDBC(JDBCMetaDataConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor.checkConfig(HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor.java:293)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.hibernate.wizards.HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor.isValid(HibernateCodeGenWizardDescriptor.java:185)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateStateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:874)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:822)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.updateState(TemplateWizard.java:761)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewFileWizard.updateState(NewFileWizard.java:135)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor._updateState(WizardDescriptor.java:800)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.goToNextStep(WizardDescriptor.java:1072)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1900(WizardDescriptor.java:92)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2208)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1516)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2000(WizardDescriptor.java:92)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2227)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:487)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1086)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1136)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1108)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:131)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.doEventAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:138)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.NbMutexEventProvider$Event.readAccess(NbMutexEventProvider.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.LazyMutexImplementation.readAccess(LazyMutexImplementation.java:94)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:218)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1093)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.showDialog(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.run(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:192)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I can't figure out where I have done my mistake. This is the file structure in the project

[image]

Please anyone help me to figure out the problem I face.

here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.198:3306/example</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">intern</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
     </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Have you added the Database specific driver connection jar? Like for MySQL we have MySQLConnector?

Comment: I have already added mysql-connector.java-5.1.23-bin.jar to the library

Comment: can you share the hibernate.cfg.xml as well ?

Comment: I shared the hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I fixed it by renaming the package where I saved the files and refactoring it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jioAo.png)